# Are all cores used automatically?

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu-cores

I am a mere astronomer, so this is quite probably an obvious question.
Having no experience with parallel computing and hardly any with optimizing performance in general: my machine has four cores. If I ignorantly run my code, will all four be utilized automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are your code is *not* executed on all cores but just one. It depends if you code using a specific platform/library that already abstracts thread management.

Depending on the language, you want to have a look at specific libraries. But [thread programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) is a general subject you have to further explore before choosing any.